# AttributeError at /admin/student/student_record/

Tags: python, django

I updated my django model, for my student app, it now looks like this

```
from django.db import models


class Student_Record(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    gpa = models.FloatField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.student_id) + ", " + self.first_name
```

there used to be an IntegerField, student_id but I removed it. I made the migrations, and everything runs fine, but when I visit the django admin panel, to manually update the database records, I get the following error

[image]

does anyone know what's going on?

I registered the model, in admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Student_Record

admin.site.register(Student_Record)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `__str__` method it still references student_id.

You should search for the field name in your whole project, there might be other occurrences elsewhere.